# Rails first app error -- Errno::ENOENT

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I had just installed rails on my windows PC through rails installer -- and i don't know a-lot about rails or anything... after i created my first app (rails new XXX), and created the first controller and view, i ran the server and the first thing i saw was an error:

```
Errno::ENOENT

    Showing C:/Sites/XXX/XXX/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

    No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs20150402-8140-cy5cjejson
      (in C:/Sites/XXX/XXX/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass)
```

again, I haven't touched my rails ever and haven't written any code yet but still got this error... i searched for hours online for an answer but none of them helped me or solved my problem... I tried installing Node.js, exejs, but nothing helped.

Note: 
I have noticed that if i remove

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

in the app template, the website runs normally (but i don't want to remove it -- I need it)

How can i solve this problem?

Edit: my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Options:**

**1)** **Removing**  `//= require_tree .` **/Ignoring the issue** - As ColinR stated above, this line should not be causing an issue in the first place. There is an actual problem with ExecJS working properly with the JavaScript runtime on your system and removing this line is just ignoring that fact.

**2) Installing Node.js** **/ Running away** - Many people seem to just end up installing Node.js and using that instead of the JavaScript runtime already on their system. While that is a valid option, it also requires additional software and only avoids the original issue, which is that ExecJS is not working properly with the JavaScript runtime already on your system. If the existing JavaScript runtime on your system is supposed to work, why not make it work instead of installing more software? According to the ExecJS creator, the runtime already built into Windows is in fact supported...

> ExecJS lets you run JavaScript code from Ruby. It automatically picks
>   the best runtime available to evaluate your JavaScript program, then
>   returns the result to you as a Ruby object.
>
> ExecJS supports these runtimes:
>
> therubyracer - Google V8 embedded within Ruby therubyrhino - Mozilla
>   Rhino embedded within JRuby Node.js Apple JavaScriptCore - Included
>   with Mac OS X Microsoft Windows Script Host (JScript) (from
>   github.com/sstephenson/execjs#execjs )

**3) Actually fixing the issue / Learning -** Use the knowledge of options 1 and 2 to search for other solutions. I can't tell you how many webpages I closed upon seeing options 1 or 2 was the accepted solution before actually finding information about the root issue we were having. The only reason we kept looking was that we couldn't believe the Rails team would (1) insert a line of code in every scaffold generated project that caused an issue, or (2) require that we install additional software just to run that default line of code. And so we eventually arrived at a fix for our root issue (your miles may vary).

**The Fix that worked for us:** On the system having issues, find ExecJS's runtimes.rb file. It looks like [this](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/blob/master/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb). Make a copy of the found file for backup. Open the original runtimes.rb for editing. Find the section that starts with the line `JScript = ExternalRuntime.new`(. In that section, on the line containing `:command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo //U",` - remove the `//U` only. Then on the line containing `:encoding    => 'UTF-16LE' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE - change UTF-16LE` to `UTF-8` . Save the changes to the file. This section of the file should now read:

```
JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
    :name        => "JScript",
    :command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
    :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
    :encoding    => 'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
)
```

Next, stop then restart your Rails server and refresh the page in your browser that produced the original error. Hopefully the page loads without error now. Here's the ExecJS issue thread where we originally posted our results: https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/issues/81#issuecomment-9892952

If this did not fix the issue, you can always overwrite the modified runtimes.rb with the backup copy you (hopefully) made and everything will be back to square one. In that case, consider option 3 and keep searching. Let us know what eventually works for you.. unless it's removing the require_tree or installing node.js, there's plenty of that going around already. :)

Comment: Sorry, I tried number 3 already, tried installing node.js -- didn't help, the problem i had isn't the same as the one you are trying to fix:(

Answer (score 0):

Change sass-rails version to 4.0.3 and leave the rest as it is. Remove Gemfile.lock when necessary, and then:

```
bundle update
bundle install
```

**Finally**, don't forget to restart your rails server!

Comment: not it is showing me this error:  `Showing C:/Sites/temp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs20150402-7900-l8y4j5json
  (in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)`

Comment: added it (before the change you suggested)